# Where to store large files fetched initially in a IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

My app downloads at start a sqlite database about 300MB. After the download is done, this sqlite database should be available during the installtime of the app (years :-)) . I don't know where to store this files.

I started to store the data in the library path as follow (swift)

```
var sDataPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);
```

No I realize that this path changes during development and testing with the IOS Simulator. Example:
1. I start the app the first time in OIS Simulator. The Evaluated Path is

```
[/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/19E2CB7E-3ABB-4C0A-8B49-39A0BE392A93/data/Containers/Data/Application/5EE51B55-0A89-45FB-A1E2-9BE3DCD33463/Library]
```

2. The App downloads the data. This takes some minutes.
3. I close the simulator and restart also xcode 
4. I start the app again in the simulator and expect to have the already downloaded data in my apps' library path. But no ...
5. the app evaluates a new path, which has another ID in the Path:

```
[/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/19E2CB7E-3ABB-4C0A-8B49-39A0BE392A93/data/Containers/Data/Application/429206E9-00EA-45EF-BE6E-4B2E9374BAF5/Library]
```

6. And the app downloads the content again.

I would like to have a static path over the lifetime of the device. What am I doing wrong or what should I change ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is changing on the simulator but it will be the same on a real device.

If I'm not wrong, on the simulator the path change every time you restart it. On a device the path will change only if you delete and reinstall your application.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So if I have to download a big file every start I will have a problem. Is there a clever way to handle/test the same app in simulator and on real device. I mean should I detect in code if simulator is running and set a static path. What is the common appraoch for this situation ?

Comment: i don't get it because the path TO your sandbox should be irrelevant. the path relative to your apps own root will always equal

Comment: I don't get it. My question is. How do I get a path (Without doing a static String by my self) , which is always the same , even I restart my mac. So at the end the simulator will find my files again, after it was downloaded in the first session. Otherwise testing would mean, that every start it will download for 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should save downloaded image to document directory. In this way images can load fastly. If u want to overcome of reloading cell then you have to check for then file path whether is fill is there or not.

```
- (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name folder:(NSString*)folderName{
    return [[self pathToPatientPhotoFolder:folderName] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}

- (NSString *)pathToPatientPhotoFolder:(NSString *)folderName {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                    YES) lastObject];
    NSString *patientPhotoFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];

    // Create the folder if necessary
    BOOL isDir = NO;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:patientPhotoFolder
                       isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:patientPhotoFolder
           withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                            attributes:nil
                                 error:nil];
    }
    return patientPhotoFolder;
}
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
{…..

NSURL *urla = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    NSString *thumbnailCacheKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thumb-%@",[self.imageIDarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self documentsPathForFileName:thumbnailCacheKey folder:@"thumb"]];

if (!image){
    //first download image here and then save that image like:
    NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"thumb"];
    // New Folder is your folder name
    NSError *error = nil;
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

            NSString *filePath = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:thumbnailCacheKey];
            NSData *pngData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
                [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
else{// image is already downloaded, so just set that image
    cell.imageView.image = image;
}
….
}
```

This code creates folder in your DocumentDirectory and save image there and fetch from there. I save with one unique photoID so that image can not be same. You can save with your requirement.

Comment: The problem remains the same. The Path changes after a new restart. At least after a reboot of the mac. This way I can't test my app, when the evaluated path does change every time.

Comment: have you tried? In my code i am not saved with fixed path. Just add two methods and apply same code.

Answer (score 0):

You should store it on Cache folder.

```
NSString *cachesPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *cacheFile = [cachesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.plist"];
```

Store large file in other directory will be rejected by apple app review team (as i have faced)

Comment: My sqlite database should be stored for the entire App install time. So I don't think the cache directory would be a good place. Even that, the path changes at every simulator start.